# How to correctly import module in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-import, python-module

Here is the structure:

```
-app-l1
  -src
    -__init__.py
    -my_module.py
  -tests
    -__init__.py
    -test_my_module.py
```

I'm trying to import all functions from `my_module` to `test_my_module.py` for unittesting.

I've tried:
`from ..src.my_module import my_module`
which returns
`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Also tried:
`from src.my_module import my_module`
which returns
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src.my_module'`

Printing out `sys.path`shows that it's only looking inside `tests` directory.
How do I correctly specify where to look for the module?

Any help would be really nice!
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Comment: @Gugu72 I'm trying to find a way that wouldn't include sys.path modifications

Comment: If you read the answers, there is one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50194143/12134355

Comment: But that involves a virtual environment and install my_module with pip. Isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: Well, you should already have a venv for each projects.
And no, if there's an easier way we would have told you instead of giving hard ways, isn't it?

Comment: Add an empty `__init__.py` under `app-l1`. Then going up one level with `..` will work.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the PYTHONPATH. Python will look for modules in all the paths you added to your PYTHONPATH variable.
You can save it in your bashrc if you don't want to set it each time again.
If you like conda env you can also add variables to your env like this:

```
conda env config vars set PYTHONPATH=value
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29965143)